# Live updating of chart in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

My app is fetching some market live data from a web service and displaying them on a chart.

On the `X` axis I would have time of an event. The problem is I can have several results from the same moment or within one second, or I can have gaps there - so it's not the case that I can have a set number of `x` points and for each one of them - a single point on my chart. Also points on the chart won't be distributed equally on against the X axis.

I'm also looking for something that could be updated as the data flows in - including the scaling of the `X` and `Y` axis. It would be perfect if I could scroll and zoom in/out (like on a `UIScrollView`) the whole chart.

Is there a ready-made solution for such a case? Preferably one that allows for some good customization of its looks? I'm wondering if [`ios-charts`](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) could help in that?

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, `ios-charts` does not support well for the time-style x axis, if the time range spans widely. `ios-charts` distribute equally for each value on x axis, so to reflect the real time-style axis, you have to generate many x values as each second/hour/day etc, but you don't add any y value for these x values.

for the second question, `ios-chats` can update the chart by `moveViewToX`, but the animation couterpart is not implemented yet. `ios-charts` one great feature is it supports zoom/scale for axis-based charts (excluding pie chart, radar chart). The zoom/scale is implemented via CG.

For other potential charts, if you can use swift, then there is `SwiftChart`, `CorePlot` (seems a little old) on github, and `Shinobi Chart` (not free)

I guess you could give a try with ios-charts, search/open issues to see if anything you needed is carried out.